# Make true or false in session with array conditon (implement as Login) php

Tags: php

I want to go generate Login form with menu condition (from database), but in session if i always problem Error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Notes : On line 44,45 are `$_SESSION['barang']` and `$_SESSION['transaksi']`

The code is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$_POST[username]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'"; $result = mysql_query($sql); $temukan = mysql_num_rows($result); if ($temukan > 0) {  $log = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];  $hak_akses = explode(", ", $log['hak_akses']);  $_SESSION['barang'] = !empty(in_array("barang", $hak_akses)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";  $_SESSION['transaksi'] = !empty(in_array("transaksi", $hak_akses)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";  header("location:halaman_utama.php"); } else {  echo"Gagal Login ..."; }
```

Comment: Why do you pass the result of `in_array` through `empty`?

Comment: sorry but i'm new in the programmer world, i think it's for blank check or not in array. so, what do you think it should look like? thank you

Comment: please indent your code properly and while you're at it, add more code. There isn't enough to support it.

Comment: you came here asking for help yet you won't go any further; well guess what? Me neither. Good luck, I've left the question.

Comment: Don't post all the code on a single line. It cannot be read and understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step should be to properly [style your code](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) so that others (and yourself!) can easily read it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$_POST[username]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$temukan = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($temukan > 0) {
    $log = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $hak_akses = explode(", ", $log['hak_akses']);

    $_SESSION['barang'] = !empty(in_array("barang", $hak_akses)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
    $_SESSION['transaksi'] = !empty(in_array("transaksi", $hak_akses)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";

    header("location:halaman_utama.php");
} else {
    echo"Gagal Login ...";
}
```

The function [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` already, so you probably want something more like:

`$_SESSION['barang'] = in_array("barang", $hak_akses) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";`

`$_SESSION['transaksi'] = in_array("transaksi", $hak_akses) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";`

Unless you need to store the actual strings `TRUE` or `FALSE` in the `$_SESSION` variable, then an even more simple solution would be:

`$_SESSION['barang'] = in_array("barang", $hak_akses);`

`$_SESSION['transaksi'] = in_array("transaksi", $hak_akses);`

This will will store `1` if the the string is in the array or `0` if it is not.

Comment: Thanks bro, you are the best Ever ever...sorry for my bad skills. hikkks.. :D